# AI Parameters for Tetris-like Game

Tags: optimization, algorithms, artificial-intelligence

I am building an AI to play a variation of Tetris. The rules are changed in that there are 19 different types of pieces, rotation is not allowed, and the pieces can be placed anywhere in a 10X10 grid. Also, a line is removed once it is full (all 10 cells contain some block). I was trying to figure out which parameters I might choose in order to optimise how the game is played. Some obvious parameters which I thought of:

a) A piece should be placed in a position where it forms the maximum number of full lines, as they can be removed in the next step.

b) A piece should be placed to minimise the 'bumpiness' or roughness of the topmost surface, i.e, it should be as level as possible.

c) This is arguable, but the AI should try to keep as minimum height as possible.

But the AI is still not playing good enough and keeps getting stuck. I would like to know if there are some other important parameters which I may be missing?

Comment: Probably not the right venue for this question. What about stackoverflow?

Comment: @par I've reached my question limit there. Thought I might ask here as it involves logical thinking.

Comment: I'm not sure you're asking the right question here - why should a good strategy be about optimizing some easily described parameter? It seems to me that heuristics can be useful to cutting down a search space, but you'll be limited unless you employ a more sophisticated structure (e.g. looking multiple moves ahead based on the probabilities of pieces appearing or employing machine learning).

Comment: @MiloBrandt currently I'm brute-forcing all possible positions of the piece and seeing in which position the 'score' is maximised, which includes these parameters among a few others. I don't understand which heuristics you mean?

Comment: @MahatmaGandhi The heuristic is the 'score' you are maximizing. That is to contrast it with the fact that, given the scoring algorithm for the game overall, and the probabilities of various pieces showing up, there is an *actual* expected score for each possible move, but it is computationally prohibitive to calculate. Thus, your method estimates this 'score' as a heuristic - however, it seems unlikely that one can make a good estimate without also having the program consider, "If I place this piece here, what will my prospects next move look like?"

Comment: @MiloBrandt so basically I should 'look ahead' to see if my algorithm performs well if I place a certain piece in a certain position?

Comment: [Game Development](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com)